# How to round so it actually rounds?

Tags: python-3.x, currency

I have found a problem where the `round()` function doesn't work.
Here is a shortened version of my code below:

```
#imports
from getkey import getkey
#variables or smth 
money = 0


#cursor to start and end for inputs


def to_start():

    print(up_line*42)

def to_end():

    for x in range(2):

        print()

def money_show():

    to_start()

    for x in range(4):

        print()

    round(money,1)

  

    print(f"${money}",end = r)

    to_end()

while True:
    money_show()
    click = getkey()
    if click == "\n"
        money += 1
```

Even if I did `round(money)` with no number after, like I saw in another post, it still wouldn't work. The round function doesn't round money ever, in fact, I don't even know why python adds unnecessary floats in the first place lol.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output demonstrating that "The round function doesn't round money ever". I am unable to reproduce any behavior that fits that description on my end. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `round` returns a value, that you're just throwing away.

Comment: How to edit? Sorry am new xD

Comment: How would I correctly round it do u know

Comment: `money = round(money, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the rounded value to a variable and use that.